# How we can set SSL cert password in https.agent?

Tags: node.js, https

I want to convert the below PHP code into nodejs.
For curl operation, I'm using https packages.

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $SSlCertPwd);`

How we can set SSL cert password in https.agent?

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`https.Agent` takes an object with options, including `passphrase`:

```
const options = {
  hostname: '...',
  port: 443,
  path: '...',
  method: '...',
  key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem'),
  passphrase: 'super secret'
};
const agent = new https.Agent(options);
```

Comment: Are these options documented anywhere?